# Clean up log files for failed Forever.js tasks

Tags: javascript, forever

When trying to start a process using Forever.js and it fails, the process continues to appear in the `forever list` output as `stopped`. In this screenshot, this the case with all 4 `stopped` processes:

[image]

What's the right way to remove those? Should I use the `cleanlogs` command? What if I want to preserve the log files but just remove those processes from the output of `forever list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on my tests, it looks like this is the rule:

- If a task exit on exception, it will be marked as "STOPPED" and kept in `forever list`.
- You can use `forever stop xxx` to remove a STOPPED task from `forever list`.
- With `forever stop xxx`, the corresponding log will be cleared too. So if you want to keep the error log, move it somewhere else before `forever stop xxx`.